# Date & time format in Krusader - is it changeable at all?

Tags: krusader

Using Ubuntu 16.04. I like Krusader, but can't figure out how it is possible to change date/time format for the Modified column. I truied to change system regional settings, but Krusader ignores them (while, e.g., Midnight Commander uses system settings). Switching application language (in Help menu) also does not affect the date/time format. I like the 24-hour format, not PM/AM, and I may prefer even to hide time, and leave only date. Is that possible in Krusader?

The other post is of no help, as there is no even such file in mys systems as ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after intensive googling I found the answer myself.

This is where all have to be done:
~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals

In this file I had no section for locale. After adding the following lines:

```
[Locale]
Charset=iso8859-1
Country=ru
DateFormatShort=%d %b/%y
Language=en_US
MonetaryThousandsSeparator=$0.$0
ThousandsSeparator=$0.$0
```

I now may change the date/time format in Krusader just as I want, by playing with DateFormatShort.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 in Ubuntu?

Comment: I would mark this as a solving answer.

Comment: On my system the file might be at ~/.config/kdeglobals. What would be the right thing to let Krusader show date in ISO-8601 (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) format despite German locale settings?

Comment: I tried DateFormatShort=%Y-%m-%d in anadded section [locale] in  ~/.config/kdeglobals. It did not work. I also tried it in the file ~/.config/krusaderrc which also seems to be related to Krusader. but it also did not work.

Comment: `~/.kde` no longer exists in KDE Plasma 5.27.7 (on Fedora 38).