# Change time format in Krusader on Ubuntu

Tags: format, time, krusader

Is there really a way to change Krusader's time format from PM/AM to 24 hours, in Ubuntu? I've seen the other post (marked as duplicate) and the real one, but it's not clear which are the steps or the files to change inside Ubuntu. If anyone knows the right way, please put the complete steps or terminal commands. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which other posts?

Comment: Here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886413/date-time-format-in-krusader-is-it-changeable-at-all and the one marked as the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/635117/what-is-the-thing-in-kde-that-override-my-locale-settings

Comment: So the answer was exactly the 1st answer of this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886413/date-time-format-in-krusader-is-it-changeable-at-all

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate, as I said, the answer was in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the first response (author's) of this question: Date & time format in Krusader - is it changeable at all?. Basically, all i needed to do was to add an [Locale] section in kdeglobals file (gedit ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals).